# Utility to automatically acquire and print generated syslog entries from command currently being ran?

Tags: bash

I'm trying to troubleshoot a command that seems to exit cleanly, but obviously generates some kind of log output in `/var/log/syslog`. Is there a tool or command I could use in addition that would just automatically grab log messages generated by this command and output them to the terminal after the command exits?

Comment: What is the command?

Answer (score 0):

`glogg` is a handy tool to zoom into a selected log file (like `/var/log/syslog` or `/var/log/syslog.1`) at a specific point. This makes it easy to review what happened immediately before/after a desired event.

```
glogg is a multi-platform GUI application to browse and search through long or
complex log files. It is designed with programmers and system administrators
in mind and can be seen as a graphical, interactive combination of grep and
less.

Main features include:
 * Accept egrep regular expression to search or filter the log.
 * Interactively display results of the search in a second, filtered window.
 * Colorize the log and the search results.
 * Read the file directly from disk, without loading it into memory.
 * Happily handle big (>4 GiB) files.
 * Read UTF-8 and ISO-8859-1 encoded files.
 * Follow a log in real-time as it is written to disk.
 * Allow one to insert marks in the logs to interesting lines.
 * Support less/vim like keyboard commands to move around the file.
```

`sudo apt-get update` # update software database

`sudo apt-get install glogg` # install glogg

Comment: There's `journalctl --follow`, `tail -f /var/log/syslog | grep --line-buffered message`

Answer (score 0):

With journalctl you can pass binary as an argument:

`journalctl --follow /path/to/binary`

pattern or identifier:

`journalctl --follow --grep='pattern'` # see pcre2pattern(3)

`journalctl --follow --identifier dbus-daemon`

Current command:

`(logger --id "test" & sleep 0.1 && journalctl --quiet _PID=$!)`

`(logger --id "test" & sleep 0.1 && grep -F "[$!]" /var/log/syslog)`